# Flutter background service: onStart method must be a top-level or static function

Tags: flutter, dart, background-service

E/flutter (28533): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: onStart method must be a top-level or static function
E/flutter (28533): #0      FlutterBackgroundServiceAndroid.configure (package:flutter_background_service_android/flutter_background_service_android.dart:60:7)
E/flutter (28533): #1      FlutterBackgroundService.configure (package:flutter_background_service/flutter_background_service.dart:20:17)
E/flutter (28533): #2      initializeService (package:park_space/tow_home/tow_home_screen.dart:68:17)
E/flutter (28533): #3      _TowHomeScreenState.getData.. (package:park_space/tow_home/tow_home_screen.dart:126:15)
E/flutter (28533):

`Here's my code:`

```
Future<void> initializeService() async {
  print('sulod');
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();

  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  void onStart(ServiceInstance serviceInstance) async {
    DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();
    if (serviceInstance is AndroidServiceInstance) {
      serviceInstance.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
        serviceInstance.setAsForegroundService();
      });

      serviceInstance.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
        serviceInstance.setAsBackgroundService();
      });
    }

    serviceInstance.on('stopService').listen((event) {
      serviceInstance.stopSelf();
    });

    if (serviceInstance is AndroidServiceInstance) {
      serviceInstance.setForegroundNotificationInfo(
        title: "Background Service",
        content: "Park Space background service.",
      );
    }
  }

  await service.configure(
    androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
      onStart: onStart,
      autoStart: true,
      isForegroundMode: true,
    ),
    iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
      autoStart: true,
      onForeground: onStart,
      onBackground: (ServiceInstance serviceInstance) {
        return true;
      },
    ),

  );
  

  service.startService();
}
```

I formatted the code like this because I want to pass a callBack function to initializeService function. But I'm getting this error. Is there a way to pass a callBack function into onStart from 'service.configure'? Any suggestions will greatly be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You have to put it in `main` funtion in `main.dart`, which is the entry point of the app

Comment: Thank you, but I'm just getting this error when I put the onStart function inside initializeService function in which I was trying to pass a callBack function to be called inside the onStart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using plugins that require a callback to be registered for background execution, you must define the callback as a static method in one of the two ways:

```dart
// Top-level static methods
void onStart(ServiceInstance serviceInstance) {
  // Your code here
}

bool onBackground(ServiceInstance serviceInstance) {
  return true;
}

class Foo {
  // Static methods in a class
  static void onStart(ServiceInstance serviceInstance) {
    // Your code here
  }

  static bool onBackground(ServiceInstance serviceInstance) {
    return true;
  }
}

Future<void> initializeService() async {
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
  await service.configure(
    androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
      onStart: onStart,
      autoStart: true,
      isForegroundMode: true,
    ),
    iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
      autoStart: true,
      onForeground: onStart,
      onBackground: onBackground,
    ),
  );
  service.startService();
}
```

This is because the Flutter engine needs to be able to look up the callback by name, which isn't possible for callbacks associated with a specific instance of an object or non-static context (e.g., functions declared within other functions). I go into this in more detail in the Medium article on [Flutter background execution](https://medium.com/p/2b3e40a1a124#155c), which I wrote when I implemented background execution support in Flutter a few years back.