# E/flutter Unhandled Exception: onStart method must be a top-level or static function

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, android-studio

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter_background_service/flutter_background_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter_background_service_android/flutter_background_service_android.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';


Future<void> initializeService() async {

  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
  AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel("Reminder", "forground Service",importance: Importance.high );
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin(); await
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()?.createNotificationChannel(channel);




  @pragma('vm-entry point')
  void onStart(ServiceInstance service)
  {

    DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();
    final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    if (service is AndroidServiceInstance)
    {
      service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
        service.setAsForegroundService();
      });
      service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
        service.setAsBackgroundService();
      });
    }
    service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
      service.stopSelf();
    });
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) async {
      if(service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
        if (await service.isForegroundService()) {
          flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(888, "reminder app notification",
              "shake feature available", NotificationDetails(
                  android: AndroidNotificationDetails("Reminder", "forground Service", ongoing: true)
              ));

        }
      }

    });
  }

  await service.configure(iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(), androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(onStart: onStart, isForegroundMode: true
      , autoStart: true , notificationChannelId: "Reminder" , initialNotificationTitle: "forground Service" , initialNotificationContent: "initializing"
      , foregroundServiceNotificationId: 888));
  service.startService();



}
```

this is my service class and that is how i am using it in my main.dart class

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await initializeService();
  LicenseRegistry.addLicense(() async* {
    final license = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/google_fonts/LICENSE.txt');
    yield LicenseEntryWithLineBreaks(['google_fonts'], license);
  });
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
    statusBarColor: Colors.black,
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
  ));
  runApp( MyApp());
}
```

but i am facing this error, i tried cleaning the project tried moving on start method here and their nothing is working,its my first project on flutter so i am unable to figure out whats wrong any help would be appreciated

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74397262/flutter-background-service-onstart-method-must-be-a-top-level-or-static-functio

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your `onStart` function outside of the `initializeService` you can't add this type of function in any class or function. so put it out side of the class or function.

```
  import 'dart:async';
  import 'dart:ui';
  import 'package:flutter_background_service/flutter_background_service.dart';
  import 'package:flutter_background_service_android/flutter_background_service_android.dart';
  import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

    @pragma('vm-entry point')
    void onStart(ServiceInstance service)
    {

      DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();
      final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
      if (service is AndroidServiceInstance)
      {
        service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
          service.setAsForegroundService();
        });
        service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
          service.setAsBackgroundService();
        });
      }
      service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
        service.stopSelf();
      });
      Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) async {
        if(service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
          if (await service.isForegroundService()) {
            flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(888, "reminder app notification",
                "shake feature available", NotificationDetails(
                    android: AndroidNotificationDetails("Reminder", "forground Service", ongoing: true)
                ));

          }
        }

      });
    }



  Future<void> initializeService() async {

    final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
    AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel("Reminder", "forground Service",importance: Importance.high );
    final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin(); await
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    await service.configure(iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(), androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(onStart: onStart, isForegroundMode: true
        , autoStart: true , notificationChannelId: "Reminder" , initialNotificationTitle: "forground Service" , initialNotificationContent: "initializing"
        , foregroundServiceNotificationId: 888));
    service.startService();

  }
```